# Number of visitors

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore

Can you have a look at the number of visitors - or maybe of the openings of an app at AppStore - with the help of some source? By "source" I mean something like AppAnnie, app figures, etc.

Is it possible to track these numbers free of charge, by any chance?

UPD: What I mean is I would like to know these figures for somebody else's app without bothering to ask the developer.

Answer (score 1):

iTunes Connect Analytics lets you track app store views, app units and sessions by source in the Sources tab of the specific app. You can create your own campaigns with campaign-specific links and/or use the default domain tracking. This is part of iTunes Connect, available on the dashboard.

Comment: I guess I should modify the question somehow, as the main point is to see these numbers for somebody else's app, like the list of Top Grossing, for example.